# Search values from a list in dataframe cell list and add another column with results

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column with the result of a comparison between a Dataframe cell list and a list

I have this dataframe with list values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['KB4525236', 'KB4485447', 'KB4520724', 'KB3192137', 'KB4509091']], 'B': [['a', 'b']]})
```

and a list with this value:

```
findKBs = ['KB4525236','KB4525202']
```

The expected result :

```
                                                   A       B            C
0  [KB4525236, KB4485447, KB4520724, KB3192137, K...  [a, b]  [KB4525202]
```

I don´t know how to iterate my list with the cell list and find the non matches, can you help me?

Comment: What do you want to do after comparison? Can you put some expected results for this data you have provided?

Comment: you were right, just update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply compare the 2 lists like this: Loop through the values of `findKBs` and assign them to new list if they are not in `df['A'][0]`

```
df['C'] = [[x for x in findKBs if x not in df['A'][0]]]
```

Result:

```
                                                   A       B            C
0  [KB4525236, KB4485447, KB4520724, KB3192137, K...  [a, b]  [KB4525202]
```

Comment: awesome david, list comprehensions, it is several steps above my knowledge of python. A question, What happens if I need iterate over more than one index?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a pandas-centric way you could do it,but this appears to work:

```
df['C'] = [list(filter(lambda el: True if el not in df['A'][0] else False, findKBs))]
```